# Cannot update component variables inside Angular2 promise callback & ES6

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, promise, angular2-services

I've been encountering some issues on my Angular2 website when I'm trying to update one of my custom component's binded model which it's an ajustment from data origin.

I have the following in my custom service:

```
public GetAllProcesses(): Promise<IProcess[]> {
    return this._http.get('api/processes')
                     .toPromise()
                     .then(response => response.json() as IProcess[])
                     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And then I've done the following in my component:

```
export class ProcessesDashboardComponent implements OnInit{

       bindedProcessesModel: any[] = [];

       constructor(private _mycustomservice: MyCustomService) {}

       ngOnInit() {
          this.obtainProcesses();
       }

       obtainProcesses(): void {
           this._mycustomservice.GetAllProcesses()
               .then((processesServiceData) => {

                 let bindedAdjustedProcesses: any[] = [];

                 for(let process of processesServiceData)
                 {
                   let singleProcessAdaptedData: any;

                    singleProcessAdjustedData= {
                      "Process": process.Name,
                      "Status": process.Status
                    };

                    bindedAdjustedProcesses.push(singleProcessAdjustedData);
                 }

                 return bindedAdjustedProcesses;
            })
            .then(bindedAdjustedProcesses=> this.bindedProcessesModel)
            .catch(errorMsg => {
                error = errorMsg;
                this.bindedProcessesModel = [];
            });
}
```

For some reason I don't undertand I'm unable to reach my component's variables as 'this' is always undefined in any of the callback's sections. Could you please assist on what I'm doing wrong? I'm able to retrieve data correctly but it looks like that it's not able to assign it to my component's variable.

Comment: `bindedAdjustedProcesses=> this.bindedProcessesModel` I don't think you want to discard `bindedAdjustedProcesses`.

Comment: I'm working on ES5, could this be the issue? What should be the workaround in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but you probably want `bindedAdjustedProcesses=> { this.bindedProcessesModel = bindedAdjustedProcesses;}`

Comment: I've tried that already and it provokes an infinite loop in browsers... I also tried to put first then in service and just collect response in the component but it doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want assigned result of your Promise to variable bindedProcessesModel, you should call *.then* method in this way:

```
.then((bindedAdjustedProcesses) => {
this.bindedProcessesModel = bindedAdjustedProcesses
})
```

Comment: This didn' work... the problem relies in the fact that, 'this' doesn't exist inside the callbacks...